# Transferring output of a digital circuit implemented on Baysis 3 FPGA to PC

Tags: cryptography, fpga

I want to implement a hardware random number generator on Baysis 3 board. It is jitter based model. The image of circuit is attached below for reference.[Jitter based hardware RNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DUhQ.jpg).
After implementing that I want to transfer the random bits generated from it to my computer where I can apply NIST tests on it. I tried to search web but did'nt found any proper solution of how I can transfer the data. Can anyone suggest how can this be performed.

Comment: You are likely limited to the interfaces available on your dev board. What do you have available? UART would be easiest probably. Could start by start searching for general UART demos and adapt them to your hardware.

Comment: Kilobits isn't much, but how often do you want to send? What bitrate are we talking about? 10 bps, 100 bps, 1kbps? I agree with @JulianKemmerer, UART is probably the easiest to implement on both sides, you could even use an ftdi converter to run on TTL level or lower voltages from and to two GPIO pins on your board.